# Play Framework - how to add a script to an html page when it extends other html

Tags: playframework, tags

```
My.html file has the following

#{extends "dir/parent.html" /}. Parent.html has all declarations to import css and java script files.
```

How to add css files/java script file and java script to My.html file.

Play documentation is suggesting using a variable in parent and declaring it in My.html.

The following declaration is not working
Im parent.html I use the tag

..............
   @myScript

and in My.html, I am defining the variable as below.

```
@myScript = {
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/public/tablesorter/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="@{'/public/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css'}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var $table = $('#ptTable'),
        // define pager options
........
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Play Framework 2, I suggest, as the Play Framework's documentation do, that you use parameters in your parent file, and that you specifies the values of these parameters in the child files that need specific CSS or Javascript files.

For example :

`parent.scala.html` :

```
@(moreStyles: Html = null, moreScripts: Html = null)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Defaults CSS <link ... /> -->

        @moreStyles
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Content of your page -->

        @content

        <!-- Defaults scripts <script ...></script> -->

        @moreScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

And the child file `child.scala.html` :

```
@()

@moreStyles = {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="/public/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css" />
}

@moreScripts = {
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="/public/tablesorter/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

        var $table = $('#ptTable'),
        // define pager options
        ........
    </script>
}

@parent(moreStyles, moreScripts) {
    <!-- Content -->
}
```

As you can see, I also suggest, for better performances, to declare your CSS files in the  tag, and your scripts files at the bottom of your  tag (it's even better to use a asynchronous javascript loader like RequireJS, but then you'll have to declare it in the  tag).

Hope this helps ;)